# Data Load issue in Big query

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCgUK.jpg)

I am trying to create table with attached json data but getting an error wrt new delimited line.

I was able to create the an empty table with nested columns but got an error when I tried to insert the above attached screen shot

Comment: Can you share your file content (or at least the first few lines, redacted to remove sensitive data)?